# How can I determine whether Meteor is globally installed? Should I install globally?

Tags: meteor

While trying to follow [these instructions](http://xolvio.github.io/rtd/) (on setting up testing for Meteor using RTD by Xolvio) I came across this line early on:

> Ensure you have node and Meteor and that these dependencies globally
>   installed (you may need to run this as sudo, depending on how you're
>   setup)

How can I quickly determine whether Meteor has been installed globally on this machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you followed the [instructions](http://docs.meteor.com/#quickstart) to install meteor:

```
$ curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
```

It will be installed "globally" (i.e. for all users). You can verify this just by typing:

```
$ which meteor
```

This should return (on either linux or mac):

```
/usr/local/bin/meteor
```

Executables in `/usr/local/bin` should be available to all users. If this returned something like `/home/dave/local/bin/meteor`, then it may be available only to a single user.

Comment: I actually have some doubt about this. I have `/usr/local/bin/meteor` (on Mac) but it contains the following line: `METEOR_WAREHOUSE_DIR="${METEOR_WAREHOUSE_DIR:-$HOME/.meteor}"`. So even though the script is global, it is relying on `.meteor` in my home directory.

Comment: That's correct. `meteor` is a global script which downloads its package content to a location under the current user's home directory. So while the bootstrap script is available globally, you would have different sets of cached packages if you were to switch users.