# Why am I constantly downloading meteor-tool 1.3.1

Tags: node.js, meteor

Evening.

I'm practicing with meteor and doing classes of sorts and I notice everytime I import a new project that the instructor gives or I make a new meteor create... in a new folder I'm constantly downloading the meteor-tool that takes AGES to finish, anyone know a solution or why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install meteor globally?

Have a look at this post [How can I determine whether Meteor is globally installed? Should I install globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960992/how-can-i-determine-whether-meteor-is-globally-installed-should-i-install-globa)

Comment: I figured this might be an answer, but I actually downloaded meteor directly from the website, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960992/how-can-i-determine-whether-meteor-is-globally-installed-should-i-install-globa

Comment: Hmm that seems to only work in MAC, I'm using Windows so I only used the installer, I tried feeding the command to NPM and I'm getting errors of all sorts lol...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but then I realize there is a file 
 `.meteor/release`.

In this file there is the Meteor version for the project.  Each project has been bundled with a version.  So I changed this file to the version currently I have and it worked.

To know which version I have, I executed

```
meteor --version
```